# Experience Editor 9.1 (SXA 1.8) - Infinite Loop GetDatasourceUsagesCount Call

Tags: sxa, experience-editor

We are experiencing an infinite loop call in the Experience Editor. It is a custom SXA Component so it very well could be something we are doing wrong but the call is coming from an out of the box javascript call.

1) Is there a short-term fix I can make that would disable this call or whatever is calling this method? The EE is unusable after it hits this state (clicking on a component) and will not behave until the page is refreshed.

2) Where should I look to debug why this is happening to begin with - any direction thoughts would be appreciated.

(Image - Red Arrows shows the Usage loading icon, Yellow box shows the calls that are firing infinitely.)

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more detail about how you implemented the custom component?

Comment: Best would be to share also code. It's hard to tell just from screenshot

Comment: Looks like https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10031/datasourceusagescount-request-slowing-down-experience-editor but should be fix in 9.1  is this datasource used many time? and is it working for other components?

Comment: I will post some code this weekend, just need to sanitize it a bit. In regards to the other question reference I think it is unrelated for that deals with the time it takes to make this call, where my issue is it doesn't stop making the call (the call is actually really fast). Without looking at the code for the 2) question - is there an answer for the 1) question - I would love to just disable this feature all together.